# Request.Cookies always retuns null through jQuery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, cookies, asp.net-ajax

I have jQuery Ajax call which set the cookie in server side. If the cookie exists it should append the value to cookie. The issue here is that HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies always returns null (cookie exists in browser though) when called from Ajax call.

This is happening because the HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies searches in Ajax Request URL/Page instead of the parent page.

How can i get the cookies from Original page? Any idea?

Ajax call:

```
 function GccVideos (http,gccCookieJar,captain) {
    var watchedVideos = [];
    var path = captain.path();

    init();

    this.watch = function (vguid) {
          var request = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/videos/watched',
          data: {
             VideoGuid: vguid
          }
        };
        http(request)
          .success(function(response){
            console.log('GccVideos.watched('+vguid+'): Success: ',response);
          })
          .error(function(error){
            throw new Error('GccVideos.watch('+vguid+'): '+error);
          })
        ;
      }
```

Server side code:

```
[Route("videos/watched")]
public void SetVideoWatched()
    {
         HttpCookie videoRotationCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[_config.VideoRotation.CookieName] ??
                                                new HttpCookie(_config.VideoRotation.CookieName);

       var videoItem =  _contentItemService.GetItem<VideoItem>(key);

        var videoNameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection { { videoItem.AnalyticsVideoName , videoItem.Key.ToString() } };

        if (videoRotationCookie.Values.AllKeys.Contains(videoItem.AnalyticsVideoName))
        {
            videoRotationCookie.Values.Remove(videoItem.AnalyticsVideoName);
        }

        videoRotationCookie.Path = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;

        videoRotationCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(_config.VideoRotation.Duration);

        videoRotationCookie.Values.Add(videoNameValueCollection);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(videoRotationCookie);
    }
```

Comment: Is your website and ajax api url on same domain?   If not it might be because of CORS.

Comment: Yes. The website and ajax api url are on the same domain.